# Short circuit scenario && current sources to understand short circuits

Tags: current-source, short-circuit

I created two circuits to understand what will happen when I create a short circuit to a current source (the **I1** in the first circuit will be zero A or it will remain its value at 1 A and it will behave as the second circuit ?)

**First circuit :**

[image]

**second  circuit :**

[image]

Comment: The very definition of the constant current source suggests that it will generate constant current no matter what - it's a perfect device for models, not a real-world device.

Answer (score 3):

An 1A constant current will always provide 1A constant current. It applies to both of your circuits.